# C# Combobox ID in datagridview query

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

> hi I'm Litte big english I want ComboboxID in datagridview query..
>   Aşağıdaki kod için yardıma ihtiyacım var ... Sanırmı çok kolay bir
>   şeydir ama yeni başladığım için içinden çıkamıyorum

```
    public void cmbComp_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServisHEntities Context = new ServisHEntities();
        cmbCus.DataSource = Context.SCustomers.ToList();
        cmbCus.DisplayMember = "SDescription";
        cmbCus.ValueMember = "SCustomerID";
        cmbCus.SelectedIndex = -1;
        cmbCus.Invalidate();
     }
    public void cmbCus_SelectedValueMemberChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            grdUser.DataSource = (from USR in oe.SUsers
                                  where (USR.SCustomerID == /* cmbCus.ValueMember()  I Want SCustomerID is here /// ID nin buraya gelmesini istiyorum  */ && USR.SUserStatus == true && USR.SUserType == 2)
                                  select new { USR.SUserName, USR.SUserSurname, USR.SPhone, USR.SSEmail }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Finish :)              SCustomer mycust = (SCustomer)cmbCus.SelectedItem;
            using (ServisHEntities oe = new ServisHEntities())
            {
              grdUser.DataSource = (from USR in oe.SUsers
                                      where (USR.SCustomerID == mycust.SCustomerID && USR.SUserStatus == true && USR.SUserType == 2)
                                      select new { USR.SUserName, USR.SUserSurname, USR.SPhone, USR.SSEmail }).ToList();
            }

Comment: SO Guidelines on non-English content: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/8239061

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the selected item's value.  Good luck!  You can use cmbCus.SelectedValue inline like you have in your example as well.

```
var val = cmbCus.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: Finish :)              SCustomer mycust = (SCustomer)cmbCus.SelectedItem;
            using (ServisHEntities oe = new ServisHEntities())
            {
              grdUser.DataSource = (from USR in oe.SUsers
                                      where (USR.SCustomerID == mycust.SCustomerID && USR.SUserStatus == true && USR.SUserType == 2)
                                      select new { USR.SUserName, USR.SUserSurname, USR.SPhone, USR.SSEmail }).ToList();
            }